# type '_SyncIterable<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am following up with the Google Codelabs for https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2

But the built is failing for the same

I tried with giving type of the object. but It still failed.

```
// Copyright 2018 The Flutter team. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// #docregion MyApp
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // #docregion build
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: RandomWords(),
    );
  }
  // #enddocregion build
}
// #enddocregion MyApp

// #docregion RWS-var
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final Set<WordPair> _saved = Set<WordPair>();
  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  // #enddocregion RWS-var

  // #docregion _buildSuggestions
  Widget _buildSuggestions() {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemBuilder: /*1*/ (context, i) {
          if (i.isOdd) return Divider(); /*2*/

          final index = i ~/ 2; /*3*/
          if (index >= _suggestions.length) {
            _suggestions.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
          }
          return _buildRow(_suggestions[index]);
        });
  }
  // #enddocregion _buildSuggestions

  // #docregion _buildRow
  Widget _buildRow(WordPair pair) {
    final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(pair);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        pair.asPascalCase,
        style: _biggerFont,
      ),
      trailing: Icon(
        alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (alreadySaved) {
            _saved.remove(pair);
          } else {
            _saved.add(pair);
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }
  // #enddocregion _buildRow

  // #docregion RWS-build
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Startup Name Generator'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _pushSaved),
        ],
      ),
      body: _buildSuggestions(),
    );
  }
  // #enddocregion RWS-build

  void _pushSaved() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        // Add 20 lines from here...
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          final Iterable<ListTile> tiles = _saved.map(
            (WordPair pair) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  pair.asPascalCase,
                  style: _biggerFont,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
          final List<Widget> divided = ListTile.divideTiles(
            context: context,
            tiles: tiles,
          ).toList();

          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Saved Suggestions'),
            ),
            body: ListView(children: divided),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
  // #docregion RWS-var
}
// #enddocregion RWS-var

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => RandomWordsState();
}
```

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/flutter ( 4807): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4807): The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty):
I/flutter ( 4807): type '_SyncIterable<Widget>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'
I/flutter ( 4807):
```

Comment: Exactly which line number is the error referring to?

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran your code here and I'm not getting that error at all.

The log you shared seems to have happened during hot reload. Hot reload can have such errors sometimes because your old state stays there. I think you won't have the problem if you just run your app again.

Comment: Yes, I had the exact same issue with the same tutorial. Restarting the app worked. Thanks !